# Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object - ionic and firebase

Tags: android, cordova, npm, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on setting up my ionic app in on my MAC but I keep running into an issue where, when I add in cordova-plugin-fcm, using Cordova version 8.0.0 and android version 6.4.0, I get the following error:

> Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Please note that I don't have the ios platform install on my app. Also, since I have the FCM plugin installed, I have added the google-services.json file to the root of my project.

Finally, the weirdest thing is that my project works just fine when I use my PC. However, on my MAC (which I use all the time), doesn't work with my project.

Any idea why this is not working. FYI - I have tried so many solutions online

- uninstalling and re-installing cordova
- cordova version 7.1.0
- commenting out the line below from the cordova-plugin-fcm folder fcm_config_files_process.js file:

-

```
//fs.writeFileSync("platforms/ios/" + name + "/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist", contents)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided over cordova-plugin-fcm Github issue works as per the upvotes and comments by over 100 users.

Thanks to Cesar Cruz for mentioning it. +upvote

It works for **Ionic** as for me it is the solution for my Ionic project.

The extract from my solution at:https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/213#issuecomment-357162384

The fix is to replace the code in /cordova-plugin-fcm/scripts/fcm_config_files_process.js as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

fs.ensureDirSync = function (dir) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        dir.split(path.sep).reduce(function (currentPath, folder) {
            currentPath += folder + path.sep;
            if (!fs.existsSync(currentPath)) {
                fs.mkdirSync(currentPath);
            }
            return currentPath;
        }, '');
    }
};

var config = fs.readFileSync('config.xml').toString();
var name = getValue(config, 'name');

var IOS_DIR = 'platforms/ios';
var ANDROID_DIR = 'platforms/android';

var PLATFORM = {
    IOS: {
        dest: [
            IOS_DIR + '/' + name + '/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist',
            IOS_DIR + '/' + name + '/Resources/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist'
        ],
        src: [
            'GoogleService-Info.plist',
            IOS_DIR + '/www/GoogleService-Info.plist',
            'www/GoogleService-Info.plist'
        ]
    },
    ANDROID: {
        dest: [
            ANDROID_DIR + '/google-services.json',
            ANDROID_DIR + '/app/google-services.json',
        ],
        src: [
            'google-services.json',
            ANDROID_DIR + '/assets/www/google-services.json',
            'www/google-services.json'
        ],
        stringsXml: ANDROID_DIR + '/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml'
    }
};

// Copy key files to their platform specific folders
if (directoryExists(IOS_DIR)) {
    copyKey(PLATFORM.IOS);
}
if (directoryExists(ANDROID_DIR)) {
    copyKey(PLATFORM.ANDROID, updateStringsXml)
}

function updateStringsXml(contents) {
    var json = JSON.parse(contents);
    var strings = fs.readFileSync(PLATFORM.ANDROID.stringsXml).toString();

    // strip non-default value
    strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_app_id">([^\@<]+?)</string>', 'i'), '');

    // strip non-default value
    strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_api_key">([^\@<]+?)</string>', 'i'), '');

    // strip empty lines
    strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('(\r\n|\n|\r)[ \t]*(\r\n|\n|\r)', 'gm'), '$1');

    // replace the default value
    strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_app_id">([^<]+?)</string>', 'i'), '<string name="google_app_id">' + json.client[0].client_info.mobilesdk_app_id + '</string>');

    // replace the default value
    strings = strings.replace(new RegExp('<string name="google_api_key">([^<]+?)</string>', 'i'), '<string name="google_api_key">' + json.client[0].api_key[0].current_key + '</string>');

    fs.writeFileSync(PLATFORM.ANDROID.stringsXml, strings);
}

function copyKey(platform, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < platform.src.length; i++) {
        var file = platform.src[i];
        if (fileExists(file)) {
            try {
                var contents = fs.readFileSync(file).toString();

                try {
                    platform.dest.forEach(function (destinationPath) {
                        var folder = destinationPath.substring(0, destinationPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
                        fs.ensureDirSync(folder);
                        fs.writeFileSync(destinationPath, contents);
                    });
                } catch (e) {
                    // skip
                }

                callback && callback(contents);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}

function getValue(config, name) {
    var value = config.match(new RegExp('<' + name + '>(.*?)</' + name + '>', 'i'));
    if (value && value[1]) {
        return value[1]
    } else {
        return null
    }
}

function fileExists(path) {
    try {
        return fs.statSync(path).isFile();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function directoryExists(path) {
    try {
        return fs.statSync(path).isDirectory();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

1. Make sure you have copied the above file in "plugins" folder as
   cordova copies all the cordova-plugins from node_modules directory
   to plugins directory.
2. If you have already added the platforms before modifying the file
   plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/scripts/fcm_config_files_process.js, you
   need to remove the platforms and add again.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the solution from @ketanyekale at https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/213#issuecomment-357162384
It might be useful, although is not for ionic.

Maybe you could get a clue about how to solve the issue.

It worked for me in a cordova/phonegap project.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Yes thank you @cesar-cruz , The solution did work for me.
Alternatively, you can provide a direct link to the solution using below link :
https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/213#issuecomment-357162384